# Is there a module that shares one input form for multiple entity types

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Drupal shares fields between multiple entity types.

Is there a module that shares an input form view for multiple entity types?

Configuring a form for each entity type is a headache.

Comment: How many entity types do you have, that makes to be a headache?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I have about 10+ node bundles, and I want to have a single input form for them configured all fields. If bundle doesn't have such field in form configuration it just doesn't show it.